# Rmarkdown: how to show output and codes but do not run the codes?

Tags: r, r-markdown

my problem is quite different from others'. Please read my question again.

The situation is this:

In Rmarkdown, I have this code:

```
rnorm(1)
```

Assume the first time I run the chunk I get 0.23, and the output will show in rmarkdwon '0.23', and then I write in my rmarkdown:

```
Now there is a random number 0.23
```

After `echo=TRUE` was set, then the codes will be executed and both codes and outputs will be showed again. But I don't want to executed it again. At the first time I run the codes I get an output `0.23` . I want to keep this `0.23`'and show the codes and outputs. So the codes should't be run again.

How to fix a output in rmarkdown and show the codes and output but do not run the codes again?

Don't tell me to cite the variable in rmakdown by `varibale`. I know how to cite it and that's not what am asking.

Comment: I think u need `cache=T` for that chunck

Comment: or set.seed("random number"), although to be fair, that doesn't really "fix" the code in a sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle you could solve the issue in 2 ways:

1. Do not execute the code each time the output is rendered but "remember" the results of some execution of said code and show that one on render. This can be done very easily by adding `cache=TRUE` to your chunk: `{r cache=TRUE}`. To make this completely reproducible, you should also include the option `knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.extra = knitr::rand_seed)`. Read more here: https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/#reproducibility-with-rng
2. Make sure that your code produces reproducible results. In case of generating random numbers this is doable by setting a seed, for example `set.seed(1L)`

Comment: There is a problem. After `cache = True ` was set, then I choose to `knit it to word`. However, the result in the word isn't the same as the current  output.

Comment: How do I keep the current output I see and knit it to word?